# How to get rotation value in each axis from 4x4 transformation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, 3d, matrix-calculus

I was programming 3DCG and got a 4x4 matrix like this:

```
Matrix =
([[0.99601513, 0.029798018, -0.0840575, 0.0],
[-0.020157712, 0.9933577, 0.11328788, 0.0],
[0.08687492, -0.11114215, 0.9900001, 0.0],
[0.023758167, 0.17372838, -0.37385422, 1.0]])
```

But I don't know what this matrix means.

Probably it contains position information of x, y, z, rotation information, scale information, but I don't know how to extract it.

What do you think this matrix means?

And how can I extract the following information from this matrix?

・ Rotation information around x-axis

・ Rotation information around y-axis

・ Rotation information around z-axis

Comment: It is _probably_ a rotation represented as a quaternion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation

Comment: It's a partitioned matrix representing ${\mathbb S}{\mathbb E}(3)$. The $3\times 3$ partition in the upper left is a rotation matrix, the $1\times 3$ partition at the bottom left is a translation vector, the $3\times 1$ partition in the upper right is always zero, and the $1\times 1$ partition at the bottom right is always unity. [Here is](http://www.ethaneade.org/lie.pdf) a nice document to get familiar with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the $3\times 3$ rotation matrix at the upper left
$$R = \pmatrix{
\,\,0.99601513&\,\,\,\,\,\,0.029798018&         -0.0840575  \\
   -0.020157712&       \,\,0.9933577&\,\,\,\,\,\,0.11328788 \\ 
\,\,0.08687492&           -0.11114215&\;     \,\,0.9900001 }$$
The Rodrigues formula is
$$\eqalign{
R &= I + N\sin\theta + N^2(1-\cos\theta) \\
}$$
where $N=n\times I$ is the skew symmetric cross-product matrix for the (normalized) axis of rotation vector
$n=\left[n_1\quad n_2\quad n_3\right]^T$

Since the matrices $(I,N^2)$ are symmetric and $(N-N^T)=2N$
$$\eqalign{
R-R^T
 &= 2N \sin\theta \\
\frac{R-R^T}{2\sin\theta}&=N=\pmatrix{0&-n_3&n_2\\n_3&0&-n_1\\-n_2&n_1&0}\\
}$$
But the angle of rotation can also be calculated from the trace
$$\eqalign{
{\rm tr}(N) &= 0 \\
{\rm tr}(N^2) &= {\rm tr}(nn^T-I) = (n^Tn-3) = -2 \\
{\rm tr}(R) &= 3+0-2(1-\cos\theta) \\
 &= 1+2\cos(\theta) \quad\implies \theta = \pm0.143745 \\
}$$
Pick a sign, substitute into the above, and solve for $N$ and $n$.

To convert to Euler angles or other representations, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Conversion_formulae_between_formalisms) is fairly comprehensive.